# File Upload ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Basically what I have at the moment is a ASP.NET MVC project made database first the tables take alpha numeric input but I think it would be pretty nifty to have a file upload so I can insert a picture into the database so I created a table in SQL server with an ID field and an image field with the data type image.

When i add this model and create my controller and views based on that model it doesn't create the label or editor for this field, I used DataAnnotations to give it the DataType upload but I can't find a way of actually uploading the file I tried this which works for normal input but nothing shows up is there a way of having a @HTML.FileUploadFor(model => model.Vehicle) or something along those lines.

This is what I've tried

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Vehicle)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Vehicle)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Vehicle)
</div>
```

This is my model

```
public partial class VehicleImage
{
    public int Vehicle_ID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public byte[] Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many approaches to this.

I usually use a jquery plugin called Uploadify.

Have a look at this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17520062/1581026

Another way is just by adding the following in your view inside your form:

```
<input type="file" name="Picture" />
```

Your form element needs to look like the following:

```
 @using ( Html.BeginForm( "ACTION", "CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

And then on your model that is getting passed to your POST Action you can add a attribute:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Picture {get; set; }
```

Or you can also just add it as a parameter in your POST Action:

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult SomeAction(HttpPostedFileBase Picture, .....)
```

Comment: Cheers, Picture in this instance being the name of the database field I'm uploading it into?

Comment: no, "Picture" will be an attribute in your model. You can't directly save it into your database. You will first have to change it into a byte array.

Comment: Sorry I forgot you also need to add encype = multipart/form-data as in Ajay Punekar's post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20996333/1581026. I Also added it in my post.

Comment: I keep getting this error The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: when I try to save it to the database

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a standard control or helper for files as far as I know.
However here is a nice tutorial to achieve what you want.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Furthermore, if you really want this functionality, you can write an html helper yourself.

1. by writing an extensionmethod to the HtmlHelper object
2. By declaring a code block in your view eg:

`@helper MyHelper(string id){
    <input type="file" id="@id" />
}`

Comment: Cheers I'll be looking into this

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

Create this type of **view**

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "FileUpload", 
                FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
      <input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    }
```

Here is **controller** method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
}
```

Please refer this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38970/Implementing-HTTP-File-Upload-with-ASP-NET-MVC